# How to replace text from a match (but not every match)?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sed

I want to replace `AllowOverride None` from the group that has `/var/www/` path. I'm using sed to do this but it's replacing every match.

**apache2.conf** before running the script

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**apache2.conf** after running the script

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

sed "s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/g" apache2.conf
```

**My question is:** How can I tell sed to replace where it is `/var/www/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine your substitute pattern with a range match.

```
sed -i '/<Directory \/var\/www\/>/,/<\/Directory>/{s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/g}' file.txt
```

Comment: you can add `-i` to do an in-place replacement